# Retreive file from Bot framwork with AwaitableAttachment FormFlow?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, bots

I'm building a recruitment bot for a company. The main mission of this bot is to get info from candidat, including his resume and to get all that sent by email.

I'm using FormFlow (basic) instead of dialogs, and here is the code where i get the file

```
[AttachmentContentTypeValidator(ContentType = "pdf")]
[Prompt("please, provide us your resume")]
public AwaitableAttachment file_CV;

[Prompt("Your email ?")]
public string email;

public static IForm<ProfileForm> BuildForm()
{
    return new FormBuilder<ProfileForm>()
                   .Message("thank you")
                   .Build();
}
```

If I'm not wrong, the attachment file is converted to a blob in a local storage, but in production, how should i retrieve this file to get it sent by email to the email job company? Using azure storage maybe?

Thank you.

Comment: The informations you provide are not sufficient. You should provide some code where you at least try to get the attachment and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: @sprinter252 I do get the file in an [Attachment](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d4/ded/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_connector_1_1_attachment.html) object at the end, with a contentUrl looking like this "http://localhost:54432/v3/attachments/n76d66b2095c/views/original",  i can hack it by download it with http client, but i can't find the file physically

Comment: Try using Azure Storage Explorer. Bot Framework uses Azure Storage Emulator on local Debug.

Comment: A few questions for clarification,
Which channels are you using within bot framework? (directline, facebook, webchat, etc)
Are you planning on sending several resumes at once with a job (storing them and then sending a batch all together), or do you want to email them to somewhere as they are submitted?

Comment: @MarkB for the channels, i'm planning to use directline (more specifically  webchat), and for the second question, as you mentionned i want to email them to the email jobs company as the applications  are submitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in comment, it seems that the attached pdf file that user provided is stored as attachment in **channel's blob storage**.

If you’d like to store the pdf file that user provided in custom store, such as Azure Blob Storage, you can access attachment based on `ContentUrl` and upload it to Azure Blob Storage within validation function.

***Code snippet:***

```
.Field(nameof(file_CV),
validate: async (state, value) =>
{
    var val = (AwaitableAttachment)value;

    var url = val.Attachment.ContentUrl;
    var aname = val.Attachment.Name;

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    Stream filestrem = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
    httpClient.Dispose();

    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("{storage_connect_string}");
    var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    var cloudBlobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("useruploads");
    await cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(aname);

    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(filestrem);

    ((AwaitableAttachment)value).Attachment.ContentUrl = blockBlob.Uri.ToString();


    var result = new ValidateResult { IsValid = true, Value = value };
    return result;
})
```

***Test result:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've created an example bot [here](https://github.com/nyxsys/forwardingbot) for this, as it is relatively involved.
The important code is within [ImagesForm.cs](https://github.com/nyxsys/forwardingbot/blob/master/Models/ImagesForm.cs).
The form itself stays the same, however when you create your form you will want to make sure to include onCompletion:

```
return new FormBuilder<ImagesForm>()
                    .Message("Welcome, please submit all required documents")
                    .OnCompletion(onFormCompleted)
                    .Build();
```

This will allow you to work with the responses submitted by the user.

To forward the information to an email, you have to create a proactive email message from the bot to another account (this also means you have to make sure you've got an email channel set

```
var botAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BotId"]}", id: $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BotEmail"]}".ToLower()); //botemail is cast to lower so that it can be recognized as valid
            var userAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: "Name", id: $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserEmail"]}");//all of these are additional fields within application settings
            MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(@"https://email.botframework.com/", DateTime.MaxValue); //a call to TrustServiceUrl is required to send a proactive message to a channel different from the one the user is actively using.
            var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri("https://email.botframework.com/" ));
            var conversationId = await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(botAccount, userAccount);
            IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
            message.From = botAccount;
            message.Recipient = userAccount;
            message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversationId.Id);
            message.Text = $"Resume recieved from {state.email.ToString()}"; //the actual body of the email
            message.Locale = "en-Us";
            

            message.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
            message.Attachments.Add(state.file_CV.Attachment);
```

After this, you just have to send the email to the email channel

```
            try
            {
                await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
            }
            catch (ErrorResponseException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: ", e.StackTrace);
            }
```

**NOTE**
This will *NOT* work on localhost, as the attachment includes a ContentUrl that points to an http localhost endpoint while the email channel requires an https endpoint. Make sure you deploy on azure to actually test this functionality.